# Google Reader's Feed Unique ID

Tags: google-reader

I'm building an app using Google Reader's API.  The XML for a particularly feed (aka entry) returned by Google Reader looks as follow:

```
<entry gr:crawl-timestamp-msec="1294812847894">
  <id gr:original-id="">tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/fc8597a0dcb83203</id> 
  <category term="..." scheme="http://www.google.com/reader/" label="read" /> 
  <category term="..." scheme="http://www.google.com/reader/" label="reading-list" /> 
  ...
</entry>
```

Question: is the value of the `id` element (i.e. "tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/fc8597a0dcb83203") globally unique (i.e. across all subscriptions and all Google Reader users)?  If not, what should constitute the globally unique id for a feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ID is globally unique. This is why Reader generates its own IDs (and keeps the IDs from the original feed (if any) in the gr:original-id element), to ensure that uniqueness.

Comment: thanks.  Do you have any reference for that?  I know the ID is a hash generated by Google Reader, but I read a comment from the Google Reader team somewhere stating that they wouldn't disclose the details (i.e. which data are hashed) - there's a small possibility that only the original ID is hashed then it wouldn't be unique at all..

Comment: I used to the Reader tech lead.The data that is hashed includes both the original item ID (if it's "trustworthy", i.e. it appears to be unique within the feed) and the feed URL that it came from. So even if two feeds use the ID, the Reader ID will end up being different.